# Displaying object properties from an array by DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of object. I'd like to be able to display in the HTML the object "name" property just by invoking a function from the external js file. Any help?

```js
let cakes = [{
    name: "Savarina",
    flavour: "frisca"
}, 
{
    name: "Briosa",
    flavour: "ciocolata"
}];

function renderProducts() {
    cakes.forEach( function(element) {
        document.body.innerHTML  =  `<p> ${element.name} </p>`;
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheets/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script> renderProducts();</script> 
  
    <script> src="Scripts/script.js"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First add the script and then call the function. Just change the order.

Comment: it should be like `<script> src="Scripts/script.js"</script><script> renderProducts();</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify where you want to output the information, and append it rather than just set the document html which will obviously overwrite everything.

Create an output container, like this...

```js
let cakes = [{
    name: "Savarina",
    flavour: "frisca"
}, 
{
    name: "Briosa",
    flavour: "ciocolata"
}];

function renderProducts() {
    var output = document.querySelector("#output-div");

    cakes.forEach( function(element) {
        output.innerHTML +=  `<p> ${element.name} </p>`;
    });
}

// only run the render function when the page has loaded,
// so we know the div exists.
window.addEventListener("load", renderProducts);
```

```html
<div id="output-div"></div>
```

Comment: I changed the code exactly how you said. It does make sense and I understand now where I made the mistake. But still nothing shows up in the browser. Any idea why?

Comment: The most obvious reason for it not working is that you've got the script in the page before the div that you put the output in.  I've added a load event handler in the code above, so try that now.

Comment: Now the content of the .js file is exactly how you updated it. In the html body, I got (sorry for the comment formatting): <div id="output-div"></div>

    <script> src="Scripts/script.js"</script>
    <script> renderProducts();</script> Still nothing shows up, hmm

Comment: Open the browser console (F12) and see if there are any errors.

Comment: Yeah, renderProducts is not defined in the html file.

Comment: Ah - I can see why as well.  Your script include is wrong.  Try this...  `<script src="Scripts/script.js"></script>` <- the src attribute should be inside the opening tag, not between them.

Comment: Great, thank you so much for your patience. That's an embarassing mistake.

Comment: Lol - no worries.  Easy mistake to make :)